# How do you convert an existing shared drive to Alfresco?

Tags: network-shares, administration

How do you best take an existing shared drive and turn it into an alfresco one?

Our office uses one central shared drive to store the following:

- Administration Documents.
- Employee Schedule (in Excel)
- Software/drivers and their installers
- Application specific data (proprietary formats)
- Video archive (Some videos need to be indexed but most are only to be saved for a month then deleted)

I think the searching, checkin / checkout and versioning would be invaluable to us but I can not see our department changing their current workflow. So I need to just take the existing share drive (with it's current structure) and dump it into alfresco. Then can I start telling them about checkouts and searching and stuff.

Any ideas or comments?

Comment: Hi, the question is really interesting.... did you find any solution?

Comment: No I never did. Had to use it's own directory. Then the project dropped and I never revisited this concept. By the looks of things those who use Alfresco have little need for such a thing and it seems we are the edge cases. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the easiest way:

1. Enable CIFS on Alfresco
2. On the machine that has the data, open a CIFS session to Alfresco as admin
3. Move the files by a simple drag-and-drop using your file explorer
4. Wait until the transfer completes. It can take hours or days if you have terabytes of data.
5. Then your users can mount Alfresco as a shared drive, and will see the same files as before.

This procedure works on Windows, Mac, Linux (any system that has an SMB implementation).

([CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIFS) = SMB = Windows shared folder)